# How do I use map() on an object array that has a periods in its object keys? Index notation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key, array.prototype.map

I thought for sure this would have been asked before, I tried searching but feel free to point me in the right direction.

So here's the problem data, lets call it "data":

```
[
{
   "Wetlands.WETLAND_TYPE": "Freshwater Forested/Shrub Wetland"
},
{
   "Wetlands.WETLAND_TYPE": "Lake"
},
{
   "Wetlands.WETLAND_TYPE": "Riverine"
}
]
```

JS:

```
const myWetlands = data.map(({ Wetlands.WETLAND_TYPE }) => Wetlands.WETLAND_TYPE);
console.log(myWetlands);
```

Obviously, it doesn't escape the periods in Wetlands.WETLAND_TYPE - so the logical next choice was to use ["index notation"] on it, but that doesn't work as it doesn't allow the brackets.

I know the data has awful presentation, but that's what it is at the source (blame the USFWS). I wonder if there is a better API for wetlands that I haven't found...

Is there any way to use map() here when the keys I want have periods in them?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're deconstructing it in the callback parameter? Why not use the entire object

Comment: @Axekan - Originally I was new to map() and used it in a much more complex function which required that - then I just kept using that same thing for others. Regardless, the answers below are helpful if I run across this again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't use destructuring like your example, but seems to do the job you are looking for.

```js
const origArray =  [
{
   "Wetlands.WETLAND_TYPE": "Freshwater Forested/Shrub Wetland"
},
{
   "Wetlands.WETLAND_TYPE": "Lake"
},
{
   "Wetlands.WETLAND_TYPE": "Riverine"
}
]

const myWetlands = origArray.map(item => item[ "Wetlands.WETLAND_TYPE"]);
console.log(myWetlands);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is with destructuring, but where during destructuring the name of the prop with the `.` in it is renamed to value.

```js
const origArray =  [
    {
       "Wetlands.WETLAND_TYPE": "Freshwater Forested/Shrub Wetland"
    },
    {
       "Wetlands.WETLAND_TYPE": "Lake"
    },
    {
       "Wetlands.WETLAND_TYPE": "Riverine"
    }
    ]

    const myWetlands = origArray.map(({ 'Wetlands.WETLAND_TYPE': value }) =>  value);
    console.log(myWetlands );
```